# Prevent Prisma data loss in production when migrate schema?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, prisma

I'm confused about the development team workflow for development to production database migrations. The [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/migrate-development-production) are pretty decent but there's some gaps in my mind about the proper way to do a production deploy without data loss.

My thought is why would dropping data in development ever be acceptable, because you'll end up with a migration script that will fail in production (because `prisma migrate deploy` never drops data but fails instead.. correct or can it???).

What is the proper dev to prod team convention for Prisma migrations? This is my thinking:

1. Use `db push` locally; NEVER accept data loss
2. When happy with schema changes, run `migrate dev --create-only`
3. Adjust migration scripts to avoid data loss; if data loss is necessary, change the SQL so it creates temporary tables to move the data while schema is changed, then move data back?
4. Run `migrate dev` locally to apply migrations to local database; NEVER accept data loss
5. Deploy code and run `migrate deploy` in production

Is this best practices or is there a better way to do this? I don't see why migrations that require dropped data should ever make it into source control, but maybe I'm missing something. Any help or experience would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In development:

1. Never use `db push`. Except for prototyping. After the first migration, you should use `prisma migrate dev` instead.
2. Once you have done your first migration, use `prisma migrate dev`. It will warn you about any data loss and it will ask you what's the purpose of the migration (like a `git commit -m`). At the end, it will create a new migration file and apply it to your **development** database.
3. If you have to edit a migration, to prevent data loss, have a look to this [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/customizing-migrations). Here is the process:

   1. Use `prisma migrate dev --create-only`.
   2. Edit the autogenerated migration file (you will need to write some `SQL` yourself)
   3. Then apply your edited migration with `prisma migrate dev`.

With this process, you will have a `migrations` folder with all your migrations that will keep track of your database schema evolution. You will be able to rollback to any previous migration if you need to and you will be able to deploy your migrations to your production database.

### In staging / preview / production:

All staging / preview / production environments work the same way.

In your CI/CD, you will have to run `prisma migrate deploy` instead of `prisma migrate dev`. This command accept **data loss** and will not prompt you for a migration name (to avoid blocking your building pipeline).

This command will apply all the migrations that are not applied yet.

Hope it will help!

For more infos, have a look to this [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/mental-model) as well.